# Jenkins Pipeline rebuild when failure

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am looking for a way to rebuild/restart my pipeline job if it fails at any stage automatically.

There is a plugin called Naginator but it only works for freestyle jobs, not pipeline.

I am thinking there is got to be a way to code this via the post block, i.e

```
post{
   failure { 

      ${env.JOB_NAME}.run

      mail to: 'team@example.com',
      subject: "Failed Pipeline: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}",
      body: "${env.BUILD_URL} failed, re-running another job"
   }
}
```

I have a long jenkins pipeline job for building and pushing microservices docker images to repo, code is solid, but sometimes there are network glitches that make the job fail.  So I need a way to automatically spin another one if it fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
retry(3) {
                   ${env.JOB_NAME}.run
                   mail to: 'team@example.com',
                   subject: "Failed Pipeline: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}",
                   body: "${env.BUILD_URL} failed, re-running another job"
                }
```

It will retry 3 times after failure. You can change this number according to your need.

Comment: Thank you!  I tried it at the stage level and it works.   Do you know if this works at the post{ failure  level?

Comment: I think it should work. Though I have never tried it myself. And if my solution has helped, please accept the answer. It keeps me motivated to put in more effort to answer more questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can pretty much use this with pipeline declarative syntax

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
        retry(3)
    }
    stages {
        ...
    }
}
```